How to install/ clone lumerical api to python
PS C:\Users\Lenovo YoGa> pip install lumapi
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lumapi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lumapi.

PS C:\Users\Lenovo YoGa> pip install lumapi
Tried to install lumapi for my Python project in order to allow the library to run within the program.

I don't think that You'll find this on PyPi since it seems to be a commercial product. My best guess on what to do would be to contact the Ansys Support or maybe first Read their doc on https://optics.ansys.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037824513-Python-API-overview.

I believe you're looking for the library lumaapi. If so, notice the double 'a' in the name as opposed to the single 'a' in yours.
To install its stable release (i.e. lumaapi 0.0.5), run:
pip install lumaapi

See https://pypi.org/project/lumaapi/#description
